# Predicate Logic - Natural deduction

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

Does the set of inference rules of Gentzen’s Natural Deduction have redundancy in the sense that without some rule of the system it can still be complete?

My thoughts: I came across this question and could not form a bold argument whether there is redundancy in the system or not. Note that specifically, inference rules of Gentzen’s Natural Deduction include $\forall$-intro, $\forall$-elim, $\exists$-intro, $\exists$-elim, $\wedge$-intro, $\wedge$-elim, $\lor$-intro, $\lor$-elim, $\Rightarrow$-intro, $\Rightarrow$-elim, $\neg$-intro, and $\neg$-elim.

Comment: It depends on the axioms of the system, suitable axioms can replace rules. Was it so that forall, negation and implication was enough to define all propositions. From this you could apply axioms for the other rules.

Comment: @Dole You mean negation and implication is enough to form other formulas?

Comment: Without added axioms all the introduction rules are needed, otherwise there is no way to... introduce some formula. The elimination rules are also needed since otherwise there may be no way to break a specific axiom. You can use induction to prove it...

Comment: @rentbuyel Yes, and also negation and some other operators, I forgot which, but it is easy to figure out by simply trying whether you can replace all.

Comment: @Dole I edited my post. If considering those axioms, does it imply that Gentzen's Natural Deduction include redundant procedures?

Comment: @rentbuyer, clearly $\wedge$-intro is needed to prove $A\wedge B$ from $A$ and $B$. There's no other way to get $\wedge$ in. But perhaps you are asking, for example,  in the context that we let $A\wedge B$ be an abbreviation for $\neg (A\Rightarrow \neg B)$ etc.? Are the rules for implication and negation enough to derive the rules for conjunction (and disjunction)? In that case I believe the answer is yes, I've been trying out a proof for this myself but may be doing something naive. Can you clarify if this was the intent of the question?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such redundancy, and here's an idea how to prove it.

[EDIT: I rephrased the argument to make it, hopefully, more intuitive.]

Let us focus just on the connective $\land$ for simplicity. Put yourself in the mind of someone who does not know what the expression $A\land B$ means, but wants to find out by looking at the Natural Deduction rules. One way you can read the introduction and elimination rules for $\land$ is that they impose *lower and upper bounds* on the logical strength of the expression $A\land B$. For example,

> ($\land$-intro) From $A$ and $B$ infer $A\land B$.

tells you that $A\land B$ is *at most as strong* as the combination of $A$ and $B$, whereas

> ($\land$-elim) From $A\land B$ infer $A$ or $B$.

tells you that $A\land B$ is *at least as strong* as both $A$ and $B$.

Assume now you omit the rule ($\land$-intro).  The resulting system tells you no upper bound on the logical strength of the expression $A\land B$. So intuitively, $A\land B$ could be *anything* which is at least as strong as $A$ and $B$. But then nothing prevents you from interpreting $A\land B$ in the resulting system as the strongest possible expression: a logical contradiction ($\bot$ if this atom is contained, or otherwise $p\land\lnot p$ for some fresh variable $p$). Note in particular that in replacing $A\land B$ by $\bot$ in ($\land$-elim), you obtain the sound rule

> From $\bot$ infer $A$ or $B$.

It follows that you cannot prove anything in the system which *contradicts* the interpretation of $A\land B$ as a contradiction. For example, the theorem $q\rightarrow (q\land q)$ will not be provable because $q\rightarrow \bot$ is not valid.

To make this intuition into a formal argument, consider a translation $\pi$ which replaces every subformula $A\land B$ in a formula by $\bot$. Then you can show by induction on proof length that if a formula $F$ is provable in Natural Deduction without the rule ($\land$-intro), then $\pi(F)$ is provable in Natural Deduction without ($\land$-intro) as well. It follows that the theorem $q\rightarrow (q\land q)$ is not provable without ($\land$-intro), as then so would be $\pi(q\rightarrow (q\land q))=q\rightarrow \bot$, which is not valid. Hence Natural Deduction without ($\land$-intro) is incomplete.

A similar argument can be found for the omission of other rules.

Comment: I think, because this specific translation doesn't work, it doesn't mean that there is no such redundancy. For example, isn't it fine to replace $\neg p$ with a derivation of $p \to \bot$? Though, this would mean the addition of a rule for $\bot$.

Comment: It depends on what you mean with "it is fine". If both $\bot$ and $\lnot$ are primitive symbols in your formulation of Natural Deduction, you will still need both $\bot$- and $\lnot$-rules to show, e.g., $\lnot A\equiv A\rightarrow \bot$.

Comment: If you consider $\lnot A$ to be syntactic sugar for $A\rightarrow\bot$, then of course you don't need any rules for $\lnot$. But I think this is not the kind of redundancy the OP was looking for.